# File Upload is not working

Tags: asp.net, file, file-upload

I'm using file upload in my site. I'm uploading word Document(Doc,Docx). Suddenly, it's not working. It is not getting the filename. It is showing empty!!! My Code is as follows:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1">

<table width="100%" align="center">
    <tr>
        <td style="height: 21px" align="center">
            <span class="lbl"></span>
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnResumedload" Text="Download Resume" runat="server" BackColor="Maroon"
                        ForeColor="White" Font-Bold="true" OnClick="btnResumedload_Click" Height="27px"
                        Width="195px" />
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center">
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel4" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnUploadnew" Text="Upload New" runat="server" BackColor="Maroon"
                        ForeColor="White" Font-Bold="true" OnClick="btnUploadnew_Click" Height="30px"
                        Width="198px" />
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center">
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel3" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnDel" Height="30px" Width="198px" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure?');"
                        BackColor="Maroon" ForeColor="White" Font-Bold="true" Text="Delete Resume" runat="server"
                        OnClick="btnDel_Click"></asp:Button>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center">
            <asp:Label ID="lblmsg" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Red" Visible="False"
                Height="17px" Width="855px"></asp:Label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center">
            <span class="txt">
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <%--<ajaxToolkit:AsyncFileUpload ID="fpResumenew" runat="server" Visible="false" />--%>
                        <asp:FileUpload ID="fpResumenew" runat="server" Visible="false" Width="226px" />
                    </ContentTemplate>
                    <Triggers>
                        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnUpload" />
                    </Triggers>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
            </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center">
            &nbsp;
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="vertical-align: top" align="center">
            <%--<asp:Button ID="btnUpload" Font-Bold="true" DisabledText="Processing..." Visible="false"
                        Text="Upload" BackColor="Maroon" ForeColor="White" runat="server" OnClick="btnUpload_Click" />--%>
            <cc1:ClickOnceButton ID="btnUpload" Font-Bold="true" DisabledText="Processing..."
                Visible="false" Text="Upload" BackColor="Maroon" ForeColor="White" runat="server"
                OnClick="btnUpload_Click" DisableAfterClick="True" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

```
{

    string strfilename = fp.FileName.ToString();

    if (fp.PostedFile.FileName.Trim().Length != 0)

    {

        binary = new byte[fp.PostedFile.ContentLength];

        binary = fp.FileBytes;

        doc = fp.FileName;

        contenttype = fp.PostedFile.ContentType;


    }
```

}

Just a sample!!!

---

Nothing works for me.. Problem is that I'm using three more buttons in the same page. The other buttons initializing the file upload control. So, when clicking the upload button, the file name is empty. So, I used another page for uploading the word document. Now, it is working.. !! Anyhow, I need the solution for this!! Anyone give me idea!!

Comment: How did u made my code visible?  I tried, it not came

Comment: I added a line space between follows: and the code.

Comment: vaishu your onclick function...

Comment: vaishu your aspx code is wrong place file upload inside update panel...

Answer (score 4):

Hai vaishu

FileUpload controls are not compatible with UpdatePanel when they are used to upload files as part of an asynchronous postback.

Just check the AJAX documentation. The FileUpload control is not supported inside an UpdatePanel (http://ajax.asp.net/docs/overview/UpdatePanelOverview.aspx):

or

use asp:postbacktrigger instead of asyncpostbacktrigger

```
<asp:updatepanel runat="server" id="UpdatePanel1">
    <contenttemplate>
        <asp:FileUpload runat="server" id="FileUpload1" />
        <asp:button runat="server" id="ButtonSubmit" text="Postback" />
    </contenttemplate>
    <triggers>
        <asp:postbacktrigger controlid="ButtonSubmit" />
    </triggers>

</asp:updatepanel>
```

or

use ajax for asynchronous file upload:

http://www.asp.net/(S(fu2l2uzphr2u3u45q2dnez55))/ajax/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/AsyncFileUpload/AsyncFileUpload.aspx

Comment: No.... It's not working. The file upload control is not taking any values. Dono, whr is the problem!!!

Comment: check you question aspx one ... File upload is outside update panel

Comment: "Object Reference not set to an instance of object" This is the error I got. Means, the file upload is empty. That's the problem with both the Control. I tried in that way too.. But, no use!!! Actually, already I'm using update panel in master page.

Comment: Somewhere File Upload control get refresh after the button click.. Dono where!!

Comment: S.. I changed that too... No use!

Comment: Hi! I found the problem. As I'm using two more buttons in the same page which is the cause of refreshing the file upload control. Now, wat is the solution for this? Plz, tell me!!

Comment: Can you give the names of buttons you use and for what that buttons are used

Comment: Hai vaishu Try to set updateMode="Conditional" for your update panel which contains fileupload control...

Comment: Vaishu if you dont mind plz send your aspx code and aspx.cs code to chendur.pandiya@gmail.com and i ll let you know what the prob is...

Answer (score 2):

The reason that the postback trigger is not working in your case is because the FileUpload Control is set to visible=false.  If you use display:none instead, the postback trigger will work.

Answer (score 0):

This works just fine, I finally solved the issue... the ButtonSubmit is reload by the trigger so the page got the info from the control.

```
 <asp:updatepanel runat="server" id="UpdatePanel1">
     <contenttemplate>
         <asp:FileUpload runat="server" id="FileUpload1" />
         <asp:button runat="server" id="ButtonSubmit" text="Postback" />
     </contenttemplate>
     <triggers>
         <asp:postbacktrigger controlid="ButtonSubmit" />
     </triggers>

 </asp:updatepanel>
```